# More than one '-e' in sed on OSX

Tags: macos, sed

I need to run `sed -e 'command' -e 'command' file.txt` but I get this error on mac: `sed: -e: No such file or directory`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Works fine here - can you show the exact command you're using?

Comment: sed -i -e "s/\.$REGIONID\./\./" -e "/\.$NONREGIONID\./d" application.conf

Comment: You can't use `-i` without an extension, and your second `-e` doesn't start with a command.

Comment: The second `-e` looks fine to me: It starts with an address, which is followed by a command. Perfectly valid.

Comment: Yup - reading without comprehending.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks @CarlNorum. In fact the `i` without an extension was the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine with my `sed`:

```
$ echo ax | sed -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/x/y/'
by
$ uname -a
Darwin Equinox.local 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ which sed
/usr/bin/sed
```

So the problem must be elsewhere. Judging by your command given in comments, I would try passing the `''` argument to the `-i` option:

```
$ sed -i '' -e "s/\.$REGIONID\./\./" -e "/\.$NONREGIONID\./d" application.conf
```

With the caveat described in the man page:

> If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved. It is
>   not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing
>   files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where
>   disk space is exhausted, etc.